# Adding linting to autotools-based build system

Tags: c++, autotools, lint

I want to add cpplint.py (https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cpplint/cpplint.py) to an autotools-based project. Does any one know the right way to do this?

Comment: The flip answer would be `dist_noinst_SCRIPTS = cpplint.py`, but perhaps you mean how to run the linter as part of `make check`? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Ideally as part of the default target for make itself. I would like it to be similar to how the compiler/preprocessor runs on a particular source file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume you want to run the linter on all `.cpp` source files as part of `make`. Let's also assume the linter is in your path and you are not distributing a copy of it as part of your package.

First of all check to make sure you have the linter available in `configure.ac`:

```
AC_PATH_PROG([CPPLINT], [cpplint.py], [true])
AS_IF([test "x$CPPLINT" = xtrue],
    [AC_MSG_WARN([We recommend cpplint.py for developing this package.
Get it from https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cpplint/cpplint.py
and put it in your path, or point the CPPLINT environment variable at it.])])
```

See below for the explanation of `true` which in this case does not mean the Boolean true value. If you want to make the linter an absolute requirement, use `AC_MSG_ERROR` instead.

The best way to make it run is to write Makefile code and hook it into Automake's `all-local` target. If the linter is not available, then this will nicely call the `true` command which will do nothing.

```
lint: $(myprogram_SOURCES)
    -$(CPPLINT) $^

all-local: lint

.PHONY: lint
```

This assumes that your source files to be linted are all stored in the variable `myprogram_SOURCES`. Depending on your setup you will probably have them in a different variable, or more than one.

If you used a stamp file instead of a phony target, you could probably even get it to lint only the changed files, using [`$?`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) instead of `$^`.

The `-` at the beginning of the recipe tells Make to ignore errors from that rule. This is important, because otherwise if you have even one linting error the build will fail! That would be very annoying because some people like to write and test rough code first, and clean it up later. On the other hand, this solution also lets people ignore linting errors entirely.

For that reason, I would recommend moving the linting to `make check`. That way, people can develop whichever way they want to, compiling with `make`, but you can require any new code to pass `make check`. To do this, remove the `-` in front of `$(CPPLINT)` and change `all-local` to `check-local`.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer. I 'll figure out a way to integrate this into my own build system.

Comment: Very nice answer.  One note: `$^` is not part of [POSIX `make`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html).  If one wants to work fully in the Autotools paradigm, then, one would choose the alternative of using `$?`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @ptomato's answer I've started doing this in projects.

```
# Make this OK to fail, tee our lint to the file as well.
LINTER_FLAGS ?= -- -I. $(AM_CPPFLAGS) $(DEFS)
%.c.lint: %.c
    - $(LINTER) $? $(LINTER_FLAGS) | tee $@

# Select only C files
# We have to abuse the auto rule above so that -j works
lint: $(subst .c,.c.lint, $(filter %.c,$(lint_files)))

.PHONY: lint

check-local: lint

clean-local:
    rm -f *.lint
```

This lets us use `clang-tidy` or `cppcheck` without too much hassle.

It also ensures `-j` works well. `$^` can be dozens of files which will make 1 lint job and take forever. This way is a little wacky, but will make 1 lint job per file.